# Transform columns to single column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to transform my data in columns to a single column.

Example data:

```
A B C 
1 2 3 
D E F
```

I want it in a single column:

```
A
1
D
B
2
E
C
3
F
```

I am using this code I found on the web.

```vb
Sub ConvertRangeToColumn()

Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range, Rng As Range
Dim rowIndex As Integer
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set Range1 = Application.Selection
Set Range1 = Application.InputBox("Source Ranges:", xTitleId, Range1.Address, Type:=8)
Set Range2 = Application.InputBox("Convert to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)
rowIndex = 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Rng In Range1.Rows
    Rng.Copy
    Range2.Offset(rowIndex, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
    rowIndex = rowIndex + Rng.Columns.Count
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This turns my data to:

```
A 
B
C 
1 
2
3 
D 
E 
F
```

As it seeks the data horizontally.

Comment: Do you need the input box or do you want to do this for every column that has data on your sheet? If so, the input box in not necessary.

Comment: The input box is necessary as my data might have varying sizes time to time.

Comment: `For Each Rng In Range1.Columns` and no transpose

Comment: The **size** of your data should have no bearing; it is the **position** of the data and you've provided no information on that beyond your sample.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
dim c as long, r as long

for c=  2 to cells(1, columns.count).end(xltoleft).column
    for r=1 to cells(rows.count, c).end(xlup).row
        cells(rows.count, "A").end(xlup).offset(1, 0) = cells(r,c)
    next r
    columns(c).clear
next c
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything though. Am I missing something?

Comment: The code was test on data that to the best of my imagination represented your own. What's missing may be an adequate description of your data;

Answer (score 1):

I only made 3 adjustments here to fit the code you found to work for your situation.

```
Sub ConvertRangeToColumn()

Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range, Rng As Range
Dim rowIndex As Integer

Set Range1 = Application.Selection
Set Range1 = Application.InputBox("Source Ranges:", xTitleId, Range1.Address, Type:=8)
Set Range2 = Application.InputBox("Convert to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)

rowIndex = 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each Rng In Range1.Columns
    Rng.Copy
    Range2.Offset(rowIndex, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=False
    rowIndex = rowIndex + Rng.Rows.Count
Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: One of you two should have corrected *'single cell'* to *'single column'*.

Answer (score 1):

Using mostly your code:

```
Sub ConvertRangeToColumn()
  Dim xTitleId$
  Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range, Rng As Range
  Dim rowIndex As Integer
  xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
  Set Range1 = Application.Selection
  Set Range1 = Application.InputBox("Source Ranges:", xTitleId, Range1.Address, Type:=8)
  Set Range2 = Application.InputBox("Convert to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)
  rowIndex = 0
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For Each Rng In Range1.Columns
      Rng.Copy
      Range2.Offset(rowIndex, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=False
      rowIndex = rowIndex + Rng.Rows.Count
  Next
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could avoid paste special and consequent clipboard clearance by handling range values only:

```
Sub ConvertRangeToColumn()
    Dim Range2 As Range
    Dim xTitleId As String
    Dim iCol As Long

    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
    Set Range2 = Application.InputBox("Convert to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8) 'get cell where to start writing down

    With Application.InputBox("Source Ranges:", xTitleId, Selection.Address, Type:=8) ' get and reference the 2D range to be "transformed" into 1 column
        For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count ' loop through referenced range columns
            Range2.Offset((iCol - 1) * .Rows.Count, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = .Columns(iCol).Value ' write referenced range current column values into 'Range2 proper row offset'
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365

Given how you want it to be ordered

- Transpose
- Unpivot after selecting all of the columns
- Delete the `Attribute` column

***Note:** when creating the table, since there are no headers, be sure to **deselect** the box that says "my table has headers"*

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table7"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type any}, {"Column2", type any}, {"Column3", type any}}),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Changed Type"),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Transposed Table", {}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Columns",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"Value", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you dispose of the new dynamic Excel functions `ArrayToText` and `Transpose` (Excel/MS365) you might use a simple udf:

```
Public Function Split2Col(rng As Range)
    Dim tmp: tmp = Evaluate("ArrayToText(Transpose(" & rng.Address(False, False, External:=True) & "))")
    Split2Col = Application.Transpose(Split(tmp, ", "))   
End Function
```